# How can I have a nullable enum serialized to an attribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a class that I need to deserialize from xml, and it has an enum property that is stored as an attribute in the xml.  Sometimes this attribute can be missing or have "" as a value.
How can I have the serializer deal with making the BorrowerResidencyType property nullable?

XML:

```
<_RESIDENCE _StreetAddress="" _City="San Jose" _State="CA" BorrowerResidencyType="" />
<_RESIDENCE _StreetAddress="" _City="San Jose" _State="CA"  />
```

C#:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute ( "System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17929" )]
[System.SerializableAttribute ()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute ( AnonymousType = true )]
public enum _RESIDENCEBorrowerResidencyType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    Current,

    /// <remarks/>
    Prior,
}

public class Test{
public string StreetAddress{get;set;}
public string City{get;set;}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute ()]
public _RESIDENCEBorrowerResidencyType BorrowerResidencyType{get;set;}
}
```

Is there another library that would handle this situation more intelligently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
public enum _RESIDENCEBorrowerResidencyType
{
    [XmlEnum(Name="")]
    Default = 0,

    Current,
    Prior
}
```

Comment: this solution will serialize with value empty string.

Comment: @OlegPolezky: You can fix that by setting a `DefaultValue` attribute on the property, e.g. `[DefaultValue(MyEnumType.Default)]`